# Default notification background color

Tags: android, notifications, android-notifications, android-notification-bar

I have a custom notification that uses a `LinearLayout` that contains an `ImageView` and a `TextView`.  Before Android 4.0 all I needed to do was swap out the text colors with the `EventContent` and `EventContent.Title` styles and all the colors looked great.

But on Android 4.0 (Ice Cream Sandwich) my custom notification background color is a light gray, and to make matters worse it clashes horribly with the default text styles.  This is strange to me, since all the other notifications have a dark-gray (almost black) color, and I haven't changed the background color at all in my layout.

Is there a way to access the default background color for notifications?  I don't want to manually set this to black (or another color) since I want it to go well with the theme on the device.  But I've looked around and can't find anything that gives me that color.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This appears to be a bug in Android 4.0.3.  See bug report for updates: http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=23863&thanks=23863&ts=1325611036

Comment: It is not a bug.  Status is "WorkingAsIntended" according to https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=23863&thanks=23863&ts=1325611036

Answer (score 6):

I also have a custom notification and found that the background color was also gray on ice cream sandwich.  I see this with other apps too, like WeatherBug.

I had no targetSdkVersion in my manifest.  I found that by adding targetSdkVersion="14" to the manifest the problem is fixed.  The background is now the appropriate color for each android version.

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="7" android:targetSdkVersion="14" />
```

Edit: Google confirms this is the correct approach.  See #16 at https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=23863&thanks=23863&ts=1325611036

Comment: Thanks.  This seems like a much better work-around than setting the background color.  I'll give this a try and let you know.

Comment: This is a very neat solution but, changing target to v14 disables the menu.

Comment: Hi Kirill.  What do you mean by disables the menu?  What menu are you referring to?

Comment: @ciscogambo Kirill means activity menu compatibility mode (displayed as three dots to the right of the Recents button)

Comment: Actually, `targetSdkVersion="9"` is enough (see explanation at http://baroqueworksdev.blogspot.ru/2012/02/custom-notifications-background-color.html)