# Enable menu on build version 11 and fixing custom notification color on ICS or Higher

Tags: android, notifications, manifest

I have the following issue, which makes a custom notification with a light gray background. I found a solution [over here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8659909/default-notification-background-color) which requires to changed the targetSdkVersion to 14. This solution works fine, but It disables the menu button.

Does anyone as a better solution? is there a way to reenable the menu?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The quick fix for this problem hard code black color for API 14+

```
if ( Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 14 )
  contentView.setInt(R.id.custom_notification, "setBackgroundColor", 0xff151515);
```

**A much neater** way to solve this problem is to use the native Notification builder with a big icon when the device is running sdk 14+.