# Custom notification background drawable style (for low priority)?

Tags: android, android-notifications, android-styles

On some devices (e.g. Huawei D1 Quad running 4.0.2) the notification background is not dark/black (instead it is light grey).

For normal priority notifications we can use a transparent background for the main text area. But what about the icon background style?

For low priority notifications we can use a transparent background for the icon, but what about the main text area background style?

For the latter, we could use android:drawable/notification_bg_low but this is only available on API16 or higher and we cannot use it for API 14, for example, because that is clearly using a different drawable.

Note: targetSdkVersion=19

Note2: This SO question did not help: [Default notification background color](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8659909/default-notification-background-color?rq=1)

Comment: The answers to this question may answer your question: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4935191