# background color of custom notification with image buttons is black in 3.1 emulator

Tags: android, background-color, android-notifications

I have custom notification with linear layout that contains four image buttons.

I set the linear layout background color to transparent color #00000000 and also i set the background color of the four image buttons to transparent color #00000000.

As Expected, According to the transparent color of linear layout and image buttons, my custom notification background color must match the emulator notification background color(almost gray).

but actually the background of notification is still black.

My minimum sdk is 11 and target is 19

Note that the other previous questions not solved my problem.

Thanks in advance, Mostafa.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use in your `XML` file

```
    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
```

instead of #00000000

Comment: I tried this, problem not solved where the background color still black

Comment: my real device is galaxy core with 4.1.2 android version and the default background color is black, so it is not logical to test on it.

Comment: Maybe you have got stuck with the `Android OS` bug of black background  this https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=23863&thanks=23863&ts=1325611036

Comment: I think this is a similar question that suffer from the same problem http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8659909/default-notification-background-color

Comment: as in the issue, this happens only with 4.0.3